# Opennlp name entity training for Multiple types

Tags: java, nlp, opennlp

I have a queries like "How many employees are there with with designation code `<START:desigcd> 123 <END>` and Salary `<START:sal> 10000 <END>` or more.

I have trained the `NameFinderME` to handle this data

```
NameFinderME.train("en", "desigcd", SampleStream, modelParams, desigNameFinderFactory);
//Training twice for different types of data
NameFinderME.train("en", "salary", SampleStream, modelParams, desigNameFinderFactory);

Span desigNumSpans[] = desigFinder.find(strInput.split(" "));
            for(Span span : desigNumSpans)
            {
                //span.gets//
                System.out.println(span);
                System.out.println("Type="+span.getType());
                System.out.println(strInput.split(" ")[span.getStart()]);
            }
```

This prints the following output.
[3..4) desigcd
Type=desigcd
123
[8..9) desigcd
Type=desigcd
10000

Why does it take the same type(desigcd) twice? Is'nt this wrong? shouldnt it be null when it prints the second time since the sentence 10000 is the sal?

Comment: Found a solution, in the training set the type to null something like NameFinderME.train("en",null,sampleStream,modelParams,desigNameFinderFactory)... I havent had a chance to understand why it is like this.                Ideally if i give the type name I want the find to pick only the tags that match the type name.

Comment: RKK got it right. I assume the `type` in `train()` function is only useful if, in the training corpus, the type is not specified explicitely in the annotations.

Comment: As a side note; if your values are always of that format (i.e. salary probably 5, 6, 7etc. digits, designation code fewer digits), and there is no(t too much) overlap, you could achieve higher accuracy with a regex based approach. See here https://www.mtnfog.com/blog/opennlps-regexnamefinder-tokenizing/ for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that both the tags 'sal' and 'desigcd' are numbers. So try to provide a feature that distinguishes the both.